# How do I make my makefile automatically link libraries?

Tags: c, makefile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double test=23.4;
    test=sqrt(test);
    printf("%f",test);
}
```

In order to compile this I use:
gcc -o test test.c -L/path/to/libs -lm

however, I would like to use my makefile in order to automatically link the math library and whatever other standard libraries I use in the future.

This is the makefile I am using:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=-lm

OBJECTS=client.o
SOURCE=client.c

client: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o client $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

all:client

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o client
```

how do I modify this makefile in order to automatically link the libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? `make` doesn't understand C or the linking process at all, it just processes the rules you give it.

Comment: It's funny how Plan 9 defined a pragma that every header files uses which does exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I'm explaining this well,I just started learning C recently. I don't want to type in gcc -o test test.c -L/path/to/libs -lm everythime I use a library. Is there a way that I can change the makefile so that it does everything that gcc -o test test.c -L/path/to/libs -lm does?

Comment: You almost have it.  LIBS=-L/path/to/libs  .

Comment: @FUZxxl: MSVC has it too (`#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")`)

Answer (score 2):

From the comments in the other answer, it appears you are using `make test` to build a different program than what is specified in the makefile (what you get when you just type `make`)  If you want that to work, you need to use the correct variable names for the default rules:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/libs
LDLIBS=-lm
```

with just that in your makefile, you can use `make test` to compile test.c into an executable named test (or `make client` to compile client.c).

If you want to compile multiple files into a single executable, you need to add rules like you have in your makefile (but instead using the standard variable names):

```
OBJECTS=client.o otherfile.o extra.o

client: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
```

**edit**

Just to be clear, the default rule that GNU-make applies to `.c` files to produce executables when there's no other rule that matches the executable is:

```
.c:
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Other versions of make do something similar (the `$(TARGET_ARCH)` and `$(LOADLIBES)` are specific to GNU make; many makes also don't have `$(CPPFLAGS)`).  You can see the default set of rules by running `make -p` in a directory with no Makefile.

You can replace the above pattern rule with something different in the Makefile if you wish, in which case make will do whatever you tell it to do.

Comment: you are right. I was somehow under the impression that the makefile would apply those rules to any file that has the extension .c. I changed every instance of "client" in the makefile to "test" and it worked.

Comment: @HarshpreetSingh: It will apply its rule to any file that has extension .c, its just that the rule it applies doesn't quite match the `client` rule in your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
LDFLAGS=-lm
LIBPATH=-L/path/to/libs

OBJECTS=client.o
SOURCE=client.c

client: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o client $(LIBPATH) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

all:client

.PHONY: clean
clean:
rm -f *~ *.o client
```

Comment: When I use this I get an error message even though it should work: /tmp/cc3kJ0AG.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1